# Solve $\sin 2x=-\cos x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm working on solving the problem  $\sin(2x)=-\cos(x)$ but I got stuck.
I got the following:

$\sin 2x=-\cos x \Leftrightarrow \sin 2x=\cos(x+\pi )\Leftrightarrow \sin 2x=\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-(x+\pi)\right)\Leftrightarrow  \sin 2x= \sin\left(-\frac{\pi }{2}-x\right)$

then I did

$2x =-\frac{\pi }{2}-x +2\pi k \Leftrightarrow 3x=\frac{\pi }{2} +2\pi k\Leftrightarrow x_1=\frac{\pi }{6}+\frac{2\pi}{3} k\ $

$2x =\pi -(-\frac{\pi }{2}-x) +2\pi k \Leftrightarrow x_2=\frac{3\pi}{2}+2\pi k$

None of these answers are correct.
 The correct answer is $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$ and $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}\pm\frac{\pi}{3}+2 k\pi$

I don't know what I'm doing wrong in my attempt.

Comment: You're making it harder by using the shifting by $\pi$ identity. Try replacing $\sin(2x)$ by $2 \sin(x) \cos(x)$ instead.

Comment: you made a mistake on the first implication. it should be $3x = -\pi/2 + 2k\pi.$  other than that your solution is correct and is a nice way to do it.

Comment: I still don't understand at all. I understand the mistake you pointed out but my solutions are still not the same as in the answer key..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sin (2x)=2 \sin x \cos x
$$
so your equation becomes :
$$
2\sin x \cos x + \cos x=0 \iff \cos x(2\sin x+1)=0
$$

Comment: To me that looks a lot harder. I don't know how to begin solving that.

Comment: You have a product, that is $0$ iff at least one of the factors is $0$. So you have to solve the two equations: $\cos x=0$ and $2 \sin x+1=0$. can you do this?

Comment: I get $cosx=0\Leftrightarrow x=\pm \frac{\pi }{2}+2\pi k$
and 
$sinx=-\frac{1}{2}\Leftrightarrow x=-\frac{\pi }{6}+2\pi k$
and
$sinx=-\frac{1}{2}\Leftrightarrow x=\pi -(-\frac{\pi }{6})+2\pi k\Leftrightarrow x=\frac{7\pi }{6}+2\pi k$

but this is 4 solutions

Comment: Note that $x=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ are the same solutions as $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+k \pi$ ( $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and$-\frac{\pi}{2}$ differs by $\pi$), and the other solutions that you have found  are the same as in OP ( written in  abit different way..

Comment: thank you for explaining. I think I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by using the double-angle identity $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ to make the equation $2\sin(x)\cos(x) = -\cos(x)$, or $2\sin(x)\cos(x) + \cos(x) = 0$. Now we can factor to obtain $\cos(x)(2\sin(x) + 1) = 0$. This means that either $\cos(x) = 0$ or $\sin(x) = -\frac{1}{2}$. Thus, the solutions are $x = \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{7\pi}{6}, \frac{3\pi}{2}, \frac{11\pi}{6},$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin 2x = -\cos x $$ 
$$2\sin x\cos x = -\cos x$$ 
$$2\sin x\cos x  + cos x= 0$$ 
$$\cos x (2\sin x + 1) = 0$$ 
$$\cos x = 0  \text{  or  }  \sin x = -\frac{1}{2}$$
$$x = (2n + 1)\frac{\pi}{2}  \text{  or  }  x = m\pi + (-1)^{m+1}\frac{\pi}{6}$$ 
where $m,n\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).  Please delete the line $$2 \sin x \cos x = 0$$ in the middle.

Comment: Sorry it was a careless mistake